python ModuleNotFoundError on conda environment
I am trying to use the Open Motion Planning Library in a conda environment.
I think that this issue is caused by the conda virtual environment not playing nicely with my setup somehow, but I have no idea what is causing this. conda list shows ompl as installed, but the python program is still failing to find the module.
First I created and activated a new conda environment:
conda create -n rcare_ompl python=3.8
conda activate rcare_ompl
I installed the ompl library:
conda install conda-forge::ompl
I installed the requirements and dependencies for the program I am using:
pip install -r requirements.txt
which contains:
cloudpickle==2.2.1
grpcio==1.51.1
gymnasium==0.29.1
numpy==1.24.2
open3d==0.16.0
opencv-contrib-python==4.5.4.60
opencv-python==4.5.4.60
pandas==1.5.3
Pillow==9.4.0
protobuf==3.19.0
pyaml==21.10.1
pybullet==3.2.5

then I ran:
pip install -e .
pip install torch
Now, when I try running a file called pg.py, I get the error below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pg.py", line 6, in <module>
    from env import MyRCareWorldEnv
  File "/home/july/rcareworld_workspace/limbrepo-bandit/env.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ompl import base as ob
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ompl'

We expect ompl to succesfully import rather than a ModuleNotFoundError
related questions that did not answer my problem:
conda environment ModuleNotFoundError for yaml but it is installed

Now, when I try running a file called pg.py What is the exact command to run the code?

I'm running python pg.py from the terminal

Can you run which python and show the output (I'm guessing python is not located inside your conda environment)

the output is /home/july/miniconda3/envs/rcare_ompl/bin/python

ompl on conda-forge is only the c++ library, no python bindings, see this issue in the github repo (https://github.com/conda-forge/ompl-feedstock/issues/14):

We currently do not build the Python bindings

You will probably need to build it from source to get the python bindings

I have installed ompl from the source using the installation instruction found here [https://ompl.kavrakilab.org/installation.html] and ran ./install-ompl-ubuntu.sh --python, however the problem persists

Make a seperate question about the build from source. Note that ./install-ompl-ubuntu.sh installs to your global python interpreter at /usr/bin/python. You will need to run cmake yourself.
